# Ad-gallery, jquery question

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to figure out how to activate the callback in one jquery plugin called Ad-gallery: http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

Anyone is familiar with such script? I want to execute my custom function each time the image is changing but the script does not allow it or smth is wrong.

Here is a basic example of what i want to achieve:

```
  $(function() {

    var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
          effect:'fade',
          afterImageVisible:function(){
             alert('test');
          }

    });  

});
```

But this property seems not to work.

Maybe someone has an idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap afterImageVisible to look like this:

```
  $(function() {

    var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
          effect:'fade',
          callbacks: {
             afterImageVisible:function(){
                alert('test');
             }
          }

    });  

});
```

About $(this) from the comment:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ad-gallery').each(function(){
        $(this)..adGallery({
              effect:'fade',
              callbacks: {
                 afterImageVisible:function(){
                    alert('test');
                 }
              }

        });
        $(this).DO_SOMETHING_TO_SPECIFIC_ELEMENT;
    });
});
```

Comment: oh my god... Such a silly mistake from my side... Did not see that. Thank you!

Comment: just did that, wanted to ask a quick question @avall If i want to manipulate the image from the callback... would $(this)... work or there is a specific way to reference to an image?

Comment: You can try using each() function to get proper $(this) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
    $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
    effect:'fade',  
    callbacks: {
        afterImageVisible: function() {
            alert('test afterImage visible');
        }
    }
});
```

Hope, it is helpfull

Comment: thank you. It is helpfull. By any chance do you know how to make a reference to currently displayed image from that callback. smth like $(this)... but it is just an object, not sure which one..

Comment: Currently 'this' is the reference to adGallery object. To access to the currently displayed image you may use 'this.current_index' or 'this.current_image'. Actually, try to dump 'this'-object and look on its properties, it should help.